# Superimposing Objects & Video

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor, video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to add animated text banners (objects) onto an edited video via Video Sequence Editor. I've watched several tutorials on this subject, though every one I have followed has failed to work. Here is what I'm working with:

[image: VSE Interface]
[image: Object Mode Interface]

I've reduced the Opacity to make it clearer what I'd like to do. So far, adding the 'Scene' has been the closest to success. I've tried adding nodes, textured planes, etc. though none were successful. With nodes, I can for render only 'Scene' (Layer 4) or the edited video (Layers 1-3), but not both.

Blend. 2.78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out that in the render settings (with 'Scene' selected), I could set the Alpha to Transparent, then change the blend settings to Over Drop.